# What does it mean by the smaller the subnet mask size, the more IP addresses are available?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I do not really understand the part where it states that the smaller the subnet mask size, the more IP addresses are available? I thought the bigger the number after the slash, the more addresses are available?

For example 10.0.0.0/8, so there will be 2^(8) combinations, am I right?

So if it is 10.0.0.0/10, so there will be 2^(10) combinations which is more than the aforementioned, am I right?

Comment: Have a look at this [article](https://geek-university.com/ccna/subnet-mask-explained/) "a subnet mask also consists of 32 bits. It is used by computers to determine the network part and the host part of an IP address." So, the the more bits for network part  (more subnets) the less you have for hosts (IPs). In addition, check this [article](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/subnetting-worked-examples/) as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier way to look at the part that's confusing you is to look at it in the way that it's stated: as a **mask**

Let's take the two examples:

```
10.0.0.0/8
```

What that means is that 8 or the 32 bits are masked by the network which leaves 24 bits available for the ip address range. The subnet mask for this is 255.0.0.0. The ip addresses available are 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 which is 16,777,216 addresses with 16,777,214 usable hosts after accounting for the network boundary and the broadcast.

```
10.0.0.0/10
```

This has 10 of the 32 bits masked by the network which leaves 22 bits available for the ip address range. The subnet mask here is 255.192.0.0 which leaves 4,194,304 addresses with 4,194,302 usable hosts.

As you can see the number after the `/` is the bits that are masked by the network and the rest is what is available to the ip addresses. You can convert it to the four octet subnet mask by adding the bit values in binary for each octet.

`/8` is 8 bits all in the first octet:

```
128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
1   1  1  1  1 1 1 1  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

That gives a total of 255 masked bits as the sum is 254 plus one more for the boundary (as it's taking up the entire octet) which begins with 0 making for a total of 255. That gives a subnet mask of 255.0.0.0.

`/10` is 10 bits with 8 in the first octet and 2 in the second octet

```
128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1  128 64
1   1  1   1 1 1 1 1  1   1  0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

That gives a total 0f 255 for the first octet and 192 for the second octet for a mask of 255.192.0.0.

When looking at it that way, you can see that the `/8` mask has more available ip addresses than the `/10` mask as the latter has more of the bits masked.

Comment: Yes. It's not 2^(8) vs. 2^(10) but 2^(32-8) vs. 2^(32-10).

Answer (score 0):

subnet masks are the same size as an address.

what you mean is if addresses have a large network portion.. 'cos then they'll have a small host portion. cos addresses are a fixed number of digits.

So if an IP address has a 3 bit network portion and a 5 bit host portion, all IP addresses on that network will and the subnet mask will. And there can be approx 2^5 hosts. Technically 2^5-2 hosts.

If the network portion is bigger and that would mean more 1s in the subnet mask, then the host portion would be smaller. And there'd be less hosts.

just like if you had to address people  and you said 456[0-9]  the 456 is fixed and the last digit is variable then you can address 10 people or 8 people if you reserve addresses 4560 and 4569 for network address and broadcast address respectively.. leaving 4561-4568 for numbering people.

a subnet mask with a large network address would be 11111100.  A subnet mask with a small network address would be 11000000.  Either way the subnet mask is 8 bits. What is different there is the size of then network portion and the size of the hosts portion.